# How can I eliminate the errors in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a simple code to create a table in SQL. It is generating errors I am unable to understand even though I am sure the syntax are correct. Here is the output of my problem in the image:
[image]

Comment: I think it wants parentheses `(` not braces `{`. And you should include your type of SQL, is it Oracle, MS, DB2?

Comment: Take a look at [CREATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-tables.html). You can not invent your own syntax and expect that it works

Comment: And last thing - USERS is likely a reserved word/table in many SQL languages. Try using a different table name.

Comment: What database provider: MS SQL, MySql, Oracle, other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be like below :

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
name varchar(128),
email varchar(128)

)
```

I highly recommend you to avoid using reserved words like Users.

A guide to help you [creating tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/creating-tables.html).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I get, the SQL syntax uses no curly braces, but just braces.
Have a look at this:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

In fact, I would recommend you to use W3 schools for every extremely simple question like this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table Users(
Name varchar(50),
Email varchar(100)
);
```

You should use `()` this brackets not {} this